# Vertical lists (going back to default from horizontal)

Tags: html, css, list

My list is floated right and I'm using some reset css, so it's horizontal. How do I make it a vertical list again? Thanks!

P.S. I've been searching for an answer for a half hour and couldn't find a relevant article.

```
<div id="nav_side-container">
 <div id="nav_side">
 <ul class="nav_side-list">
 <li>Home</li>
 <li>Professional</li>
 <li>Enterprise</li>
 <li>Service Providers</li>
 <li>Security</li>
 <li>Pricing</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>

/*Fixed Container*/
#nav_side-container {
     position:fixed;
     width: 100%;
     top: 200px;
}

/*960 wide*/
#nav_side{
     margin:0 auto;
     width:960px;
}

/*Move list right side of 960*/
.nav_side-list {
     float:right;
}
```

Comment: post code relevant to your problem

Comment: li{clear:both;} doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

try

```
.nav_side-list{
width:youwant;
}

ul.nav_side-list li{
width:100%;  

}
```

Comment: Thanks NullPointer! I'll try it.

Comment: @TylerLangan let me know if i am missing something

Comment: Hmmm... still doesn't make the list vertical. Thanks though.

Comment: I want it to scroll with the page as a fixed vertical nav bar. It needs to line up to the right of a centered 960 wide div.

Comment: @TylerLangan can you give live link